# Can i have a child div hide its parent div along with it when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For example :

```
<div id="parent">
      <div id="child">Click here</div>
</div>
```

when i click on child, both div will disappear or hidden

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes you can. Show how you tried if not worked.

Comment: Link to the code i've worked on: https://jsfiddle.net/rahul_bundoo/vqvzgrm4/1/
 when you click on Remove, the box and its content should disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by using jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function. Once you html properly render or loaded then following code will be ready to execute, this is beacuse of `$(document).ready(function() {...Execute Once HTML Render...});`

So the following code will be functional only click event as you see i am using `on('click',function(){...});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#child" ).on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hmunutqp/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery

```
$("#child").on('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/5uhta44e/)
hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with an working example https://jsfiddle.net/fdaqsks2/

```js
$("#child").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

```css
#parent{
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}

#child {
  padding:5px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
      <div id="child">Click here</div>
</div>
```